# How to write page number enclosed in parentheses in table of contents, list of figures, list of tables in overleaf?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

[image]

I want list page numbers in table of contents, list of figure, tables enclosed with parentheses in latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resultig in your screenshot? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2):

You've set the `tocloft` tag, so I'll assume that you're using a document class that is compatible with the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package.

In the following example, the macros `\cftXpagefont` and `\cftXafterpnum` -- where `X` may be `sec`, `subsec`, `fig`, or `tab` -- are redefined to meet your formatting objectives for section- and subsection-level ToC entries as well as for entries in the List of Figures and the List of Tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{(}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{(}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{(}
\renewcommand\cfttabpagefont{(}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{)}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{)}
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{)}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{)}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\bigskip
\hrule

\section{Hello}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{Hello} \end{figure}

\subsection{World}
\begin{table}[ht] \caption{World} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much the problem solved..